# Що означає вираз "скакав в ґречку"?

Tags: фразеологізми

Добрий день. Сьогодні почула такий вираз як "скакав в ґречку". Що він означає?

Comment: Якщо ж Вас влаштовують відповіді і Ви їх приймаєте, ставте, будь ласка, прапорець "✔". Таким чином збільшується рейтинг. Дякую за розуміння!

Answer (score 4):

На сайті [Світ слова](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary/3864-2013-02-13-19-13-50.html) ([Фразеологічний словник](http://svitslova.com/idioms-dictionary.html)) автори подають так:

> **Скакати, скочити в гречку** в ролі прис. — зра­джувати своїй дружині; вступати в незаконні інтимні зв'язки з сторонньою жінкою.
>
> До січового товариства вступали і жонаті, і нежо­наті, але доступ жінкам на Січ гостро заборонявся, так само заборонялося козакам баламутити заміжніх жінок, що називалося — скакати в гречку (Панч, Гомоніла Ук­раїна, 1954, стор. 226); Злі язики розпускали плітки, начебто його (Сидора Сидоровича) Жанночка скаче в гречку з Михайлом Чорногором (Дмитерко, Нарече­на, 1959, стор. 213); Голів тих знали ми чимало, — Куди їх потім заподіто?!. Бо кожен мав якусь замашку, Що викликала заперечку. Той заглядав частенько в пляшку, А той тайком скакав у гречку (Воскрекасенко, І всерйоз і жартома, 1960, стор. 26); — Дивіться, ще оступимось... Скочимо в гречку. — А чого б не скочити? (Мушкетик, Чорний хліб, 1960, стор. 105).